# What is the difference between "within five to six days" and "within six days"?

Tags: meaning

1. Symptoms will develop within five to six days after contracting the disease.
2. Symptoms will develop within six days after contracting the disease.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)? They both mean before six days have passed, don't they?

Comment: The writer wasn't thinking. Logically, it should be "five or six days after" or "within six days of".

Comment: The former suggests typically it will take 5 or 6 days and no longer, but it's not very precise so doesn't seem good for medical purposes.

Comment: No one is asking, so I will. Please supply the source of the quotes, or tell us whether you invented the two sentences yourself. It seem unlikely that anyone would write "within 5 to six days" when the maximum limit is *six days*. I could understand the indications "within 7 OR 10 days"  Meaning the infected person could get sick any day between day 7 and day 10.

Comment: You see this kind of imprecision a lot.  You probably ignore it when it happens in your native language.  Compare the expression "up to 15% or more off!" [OB xkcd](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/870:_Advertising)

Comment: If I were told "within five to six days", and developed symptoms after seven days, I would not be at all surprised. If I were told "within six days", and I developed symptoms after seven days, I would be a little bit surprised. So to me, I think the difference is that one expresses more certainty than the other. But this is just one data point, so perhaps not worth an answer.

Comment: If it was an Amazon delivery it'd both be equally wrong because it's at least 7 days.

Comment: I think there is no useful difference in either English or maths.

Who thinks there is, please explain

Comment: I might also take (1) to mean that it would be surprising to develop symptoms *sooner* than 5 days.

Answer (score 18):

The difference is that **"within 6 days"** is a clear and logical statement which means "at some point in time between now and 6 days from now", while **"within 5 to 6 days"** is an ambiguous statement with no single clear definition: it could be a sloppy way of saying *"within 6 days"*, or it could be trying to convey *"between 5 and 6 days after"*, or it could even be a sloppy way of saying *"within 5 days"*. Unless you can read the author's mind, you can't know which meaning was intended.

Comment: exactly correct

Comment: I will see you within 5 or 6 days. means from between day one to day six. A time period of five or six days begins on day 1. Saying it is clear and logical does not explain what it means. -1

Comment: @Lambie: eh? I did not say that "within 5 or 6 days" is clear and logical, because it is anything but. If you mean "I'll see you sometime in the next six days", then what is the 5 doing in there? Why not "within 3 or 6 days"? Ah, but then it needs to be "within 3 to 6 days", and it becomes increasingly obvious that "within" is the wrong word to be using.

Comment: "within 6 days" is a clear and logical statement, You did say that.

Comment: +1:  When I speak informally such as "Sure honey, I'll edge the flowerbeds within 5 to 6 days", I mean "within 6 days" as you wrote.  My thought when speaking is "sometime in the next 5 days OR 6 days".  So basically replace "to" with "or".

Comment: I agree that sentence (1) is fundamentally ambiguous.  I would personally be inclined to interpret it as something along the lines of "within 6 days, but probably closer to 5 than to 1", but I would not be prepared to argue for that as the way it necessarily *should* be interpreted.

Answer (score 17):

In direct answer to your question, *yes* - they both mean before six days have passed. However, there is a clear difference.

Cambridge defines 'within' this way:

> **inside** or **not further than** an area or period of time:

So, it can mean two things - *inside* two given points, or *no further than* a single given point.

- "*Within 6 days*" implies that the symptoms could begin at any point before the 6th day - on day 1, day 2, day 3 etc
- "*Within 5-6 days*" is a more specific time frame using two points of reference. It means that the symptoms will most likely occur on day 5 or 6 following infection.

Comment: Within 5-6 days can refer to any time during those five days or during the sixth day. Your second explanation would be: on day five or six...

Comment: @Lambie Is that evidence-based?

Comment: No, is yours? I don't see the basis for your comment. IF "*Within 6 days" implies that the symptoms could begin at any point before the 6th day - on day 1, day 2, day 3 etc,* THEN, it follows logically that OR 6 just adds another day. If something starts on the 5th or 6th day, we'd say just that: The symptoms appear on the 5th or 6h day.

Comment: @Lambie yes mine is based on the dictionary definition which makes it very clear 'within' can be used to indicate a *limit* **or** a *range*. One point indicates a limit; two would indicate a range.

Comment: Yes,  a limit or range needn't be just one day. Au contraire: Within two or three weeks extends a range to any time from 1 day to 21 days. Within 5-6 days, anytime from day 1 to day 6.

Comment: @Lambie if what you are saying were true (it isn't) then saying "within 5-6 days" instead of "within 6 days" would be a circumlocution.

Comment: I think the language is somewhat imprecise here. If you really wanted the lower bound, you could say "within _between_ five and six days after infection", which is obviously clunky, but I don't think "within" can have a definite lower bound without it. Given that it's biological in nature, I'd be more accustomed to something like "symptoms typically appear between five and six days after infection", which covers for outliers too but also sets the bound more definitely

Comment: I mean, you could take a practical example. You go to a party, start feeling ill two days later, and _then_ a group chat goes round that someone at the party has been diagnosed with a horrible contagious illness. Would "Symptoms will develop within five to six days after contracting the disease" put your mind at more ease than "symptoms typically appear between five and six days after infection"? I know I'd stress a lot less with the latter messaging. I'd still get checked, but the message definitely reduces the probability in my mind that the two events are related

Comment: inside or not further than an area or period of time: whether that's within 5 or within 5 or 6, the meaning is the same. The range is day 1 to day 5 AND day 1 to day 6.

Comment: @roganjosh: Remove "typically" from your example. It's making it so that one variant focuses on a possibility and the other on a fact, which seems to be the basis for the distinction you're making with regards to how you'd feel about it. The issue here isn't with "within".

Comment: @Lambie: _"Within two or three weeks extends a range to any time from 1 day to 21 days."_ Note the nuanced difference between _"within [two **or** three weeks]"_ (one reference point with an uncertain value = limit) and _"Within [two] **to** [three] weeks"_ (two distinct reference points = range).

Comment: @Lambie: Your last comment makes me wonder if you are either not understanding what a range is, or actively disagreeing that "within" could be used to indicate a range. The dictionary explicitly has this usage covered, so I'm not sure what it is that you're commenting on here.

Comment: I simply can't support this answer, which is on a teach-English site, because the answer does not simply state the most overwhelming fact: that the utterance is Wrong.

Comment: Thus, "So, it can mean two things" that is simply incorrect I'm afraid.  The collection of words presented means nothing.

Comment: What's the difference between "within 5 to 6 days" and "in 5 to 6 days"? You seem to be saying that they're equivalent.

Comment: This answer seems simply wrong to me; I don't recognize "within <lower bound> to <upper bound>" as *ever* meaning "within the range from <lower bound> to <upper bound>". But I see that it's gotten a bunch of upvotes, so maybe this is a dialect difference? (I'm American, FWIW.)

Comment: @ruakh The dictionary definition I quoted is quite clear, but Cambridge is predominantly British English. I've looked at Websters (the popular US English dictionary) and it has these definitions: *(1) not beyond* and *(2) in or into the range of*. So the meanings are there, whether you use them in daily speech is another matter. But to say the answer is "simply wrong" is contrary to what authoritative sources are telling you.

Comment: @Astralbee: Your authoritative sources don't disagree with me; they're simply silent on the relevant point. Certainly one sense of "within" is  "within (a given range)"; for example, we can literally say "within that range". What I'm saying is that, in my experience, "within <lower bound> to <upper bound>" never means "within the range from <lower bound> to <upper bound>".

Comment: Dictionary definitions should not be taken out of context: do any of the examples in the dictionary support the "between 5 and 6 days" interpretation? _It will rain sometime within the first 3 days of April_ is a temporal usage of "within" that matches the "inside" part of the definition, but "within X to Y" is a different construction. Note that one of these readings can be paraphrased with "during": _It will rain during the first 3 days of April_, not _*Symptoms will develop during 5 to 6 days after infection._

Answer (score 6):

**(a) Symptoms will develop within five to six days after contracting the disease.**
This statement indicates a range of possible times for symptom onset. Symptoms could show up as early as five days after contracting the disease, or as late as six days.

**(b) Symptoms will develop within six days after contracting the disease.**
This statement sets a maximum window for symptom onset. Symptoms must appear within six days, but could potentially show up earlier than five days.

Therefore, while both sentences might be interpreted similarly in casual conversation, they convey slightly different information regarding the precision of the timeframe.

Comment: Your answer says that that (a) "within five days" symptoms will develop either on day 5 or day 6, which suggests there will be no signs of symptoms on day 4 of contracting the disease. So why would a doctor, a website or whoever (it's time that users begin to tell us their sources) say "within" in the first place? Wouldn't they say "symptoms will manifest/appear/develop  between five or six days". And how is this answer any different from @Astralbee's?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I think the **within** versus **on** [days or day] is the point. But Astralbee says I'm wrong and cites the dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "between five or six days" is not the same as "within five or six days". "Between" means that if you get symptoms, it will be on day 5 or day 6. "Within" means you could get symptoms anywhere from day 1 to day 6.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Instead of engaging in arguments or giving advice on how people should ask questions, it's better to just ignore posts that you don't like. If every question and thought were complete, there would be no questions at all. It is the responder's ability that teaches learners what they can't understand and describe completely as a standard question.

Comment: @JeffC *Within" means you could get symptoms anywhere from day 1 to day 6. * but this answer doesn't say that it says `Symptoms could show up as early as five days after contracting the disease, or as late as six days.`

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's exactly what I stated in my comment for "within." My point was directed at your incorrect use of "between."

Comment: @JeffC My use of "between" is correct if symptoms manifest either on day 5 or day 6. The use of "within" in example (a) is ambiguous. It could be any day before day 6 or it could refer to the very specific period between day 5 and day 6. In fact, Style's interpretation is different from yours.  I am referring to sentence **(a)** not sentence **(b)** which I can go along with.  I hope I've explained myself more clearly. TBC I didn't cast any downvote, I just queried the answerer's interpretation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: A nitpick: we say either "five or six days after [...]" (with no "between") or "between five and six days after [...]" (with "and" rather than "or"). But either way, I agree with you: "within five to six days after [...]" doesn't mean what this answer claims it does, at least in my (American) experience.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is just a way of emphasizing the imprecision of estimates like this. I often find myself writing things like "around 5 or 6 years ago", which is clearly redundant: "around 5 years ago" already expresses that it might not be exactly that many years.

Biological processes are highly variable, so it's hard to be precise about how long something will take. "within 5 to 6 days" might mean that it's usually within 5 days, but occasionally 6 days. So if you don't experience symptoms within 5 days you're probably safe, but don't be too surprised if they appear the next day. But if you make it to 7 days, you're very likely to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a hypothetical example to test how you would receive the information. When Covid was a concern but between lockdowns, this was actually somewhat commonplace and real. Scenario:

1. You go to a party
2. Two days later you wake up feeling unwell
3. A group chat goes around at lunch time of that same day to all attendees that Bob has just been diagnosed with Uhohitis. You look it up online and find:

> A highly contagious, painful and chronic infection... Symptoms will develop within five to six days after contracting the infection.

4. Evaluate now whether you feel like there is any kind of definite lower bound set by the inclusion of that "five days" for you to take some kind of comfort from. Does it provide *any* assurance to you that your sudden-onset-sniffles isn't going to develop into Uhohitis because it's only been two days?

The other answers suggest that it sets some kind of lower bound, however implied it may be. I'd argue that it adds absolutely none - the point of medical information/language is to be as clear and as precise as possible with something that is inherently non-deterministic (in biology there will always be outliers). **My answer is therefore that they are the same - it's no different to "within six days**".

**Without symptoms** I'd take "Symptoms will develop within five to six days after contracting the disease" on day five as being "I'm in with a shot here to dodge this one" and after day six being "Ok, I made it". If I had **any kind of symptom at all**, no matter the period after exposure, I'd be really concerned. Add to that, "will develop" suggests that asymptomatic infection is not possible - you *will* have symptoms if you're infected.

I'd argue that "symptoms typically appear between five and six days after infection" is a far-better representation of the information *if indeed they wanted to set a lower bound* and suggest that two days just isn't practical in linking my party attendance and my feeling unwell. There will always be outliers, but I think the general public understands this about incubation periods even if only instinctively, and it is much better at setting expectations.

Comment: The problem is whether within 5 to 6 days has a lower bound day that is day 1. I say it does and it extends UP TO at most day 6. Do you agree?

Comment: @Lambie that's precisely my point that I made - "The other answers suggest that it sets some kind of lower bound, however implied it may be. I'd argue that it adds absolutely none". I used the example as a way of sense-checking whatever _implied_ lower bound there was. If you're not sick, you might take is as some trivial milestone to make it to day 5. If you _are_ sick, that lower bound goes out the window and you would panic from day one.

Comment: It sets no lower bound. I think we aren't using the word bound the same way: For me, the range is Day 1 through to Day 6. So, the lower bound is Day 1 and the upper one is Day 6. I read through your answer and did not understand what I just explained. Also, it's easier to follow if you say sentence one and two, or whatever.

Comment: Given that time can only move in one direction, the absence of a _specified_ lower bound means that the clock starts ticking at the moment of exposure. It obviously cannot be the day/week/year _before_ the exposure so I didn't feel the need to say that. The lower bound is determined by the physics of the universe unless specified otherwise

Comment: But that is exactly the issue. Read Astralbee's answer who says it is two different things and that's precisely because of how one interprets the bounds of this time periods that say: within 6 days or within 5 or 6 days.

Comment: I **have** read all the other answers. That's precisely why I posted my **rebuttal**. I have no idea what your point is when the whole point of _my_ post was to say exactly what you're commenting back to me here. How does **"The other answers suggest that it sets some kind of lower bound, however implied it may be. I'd argue that it adds absolutely none"** suggest I'm saying anything other than that?

Comment: For me, you may mean what I just asked you but that bolded sentence contradicts the way I understand it. Never mind, not worth arguing over.

Answer (score 1):

> Symptoms will develop **within five to six days** after contracting the disease.

Adding to Martha's, Bamar's and roganjosh's answers: let's charitably interpret the speaker's phrasing, that is, assume that they *aren't* being sloppy:

1. Perhaps because they simply can't recall, or maybe due to the literature being conflicting, they are **unsure where exactly between the 5th and 6th days the symptoms' onset's upper bound is**.

   If they had meant that the upper bound is variable between the 5th and 6th days, they would have simply said “within six days”.
2. “Within five to six days” technically must have the same lower bound as “within six days”: **symptoms could develop as early as immediately**.

In all likelihood though, the speaker *is* being sloppy, in which case I think [nschneid's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/349644/177594) is on to something: the speaker is probably trying to say that symptoms will develop **within six days—typically between the 5th and 6th days**.

Comment: Thank you all very much. I was asked if the example sentences were invented by me. They were, but I think one sees this kind of thing a lot. All you have to do is search 'within five to six days' on googlebooks, You'll find loads of examples. And there's nothing special about 'five and six days'. I think this is a real problem. Nobody seems to find the problematic sentence 'unnatural', although it seems illogical to some people (including me), I think to be on safe side, I'd assume that it is ambiguous.

Comment: @azz I just did a google search and phrases like "within five to six days" are indeed common. Anyhow, my answer is trying to charitably explain that the speaker is thinking, "I can't recall whether symptoms are known to develop within *5 days* or within *6 days* or even within *5.5 days*; whatever the case, it is definitely accurate to say that symptoms develop within *5 to 6 days*."

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, I have seen (and been confused by) a policy that said that something was requested "within 3-6 months". I initially took it as a suggestion to wait at least 3 months, but asked for clarification, and was told that 3 months was not a minimum.

It is confusing because logically, "within 6 months" would have conveyed the rule more precisely. My interpretation is that people may be "imprecise" because they are simultaneously indicating a maximum and an expected typical amount of time. (That is, normally 3-6 months is expected, and 6 is the maximum, but 3 is not a minimum.) So, "within 3-6 months" in this case probably meant "within typically at least 3 and definitely no more than 6 months".

Comment: Your final sentence as it stands is contradicting the rest of your answer; I think you mean suggest that "within 3-6 months" is probably trying to convey "definitely within 6 months, and typically between 3 and 6 months".